# Text alignment for push notifications in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My iOS application is supported in english and arabic language versions. So when the app language is english, notification is showing from (left to right) and that is perfect!

How can I do the text alignment of push notification title and description when in arabic language i.e. from right to left? Please anyone help me out on this.

Comment: No but how can I access the title and description labels received in push notification?

Comment: @MuneebRehman you'll have to create a iOS notification extension service to modify title and description of push notification

Comment: Did you try to add Unicode Right-to-left mark at the beginning of the title?

Answer (score 1):

No, You can not because handle by iOS not by the application. If the user had selected the regional & language setting RTL. Then the only iOS will handle this and automatically choose the RTL and LTR when based on content. Hope it helps
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After some testing, I discovered that the alignment depends on the content of the notification like follow:

- if the title starts with RTL letter (like the Arabic language) the alignment of the title will be RTL
- if the title starts with an LTR letter (English) the alignment will be LTR
  and the same applies to the notification body

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are handled by iOS and you don't have such control over how they're shown. I think they'll be shown RTL on devices where the user has selected correct iOS regional settings.